# How to section text that has been extracted?

Tags: python, pdf, data-mining, text-extraction

I'm trying to find a way to section the text I have already extracted into two variables. I'm using this on scientific texts and I want to extract the abstract and the rests of the articles e.g. introduction to conclusion into two, so abstract and the rest.

How I can do this? I have tried regex but could not get it to work. Below you can see some of the code I have used.

```
with pdfplumber.open("") as pdf:
    all_text = '' # new line
    for pdf_page in pdf.pages:
               single_page_text = pdf_page.extract_text()
               #print( single_page_text )

               all_texts = all_text + '\n' + single_page_text
    #print(all_text)
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your text and the regex you were using?

Comment: Apologies I didn't get too far with using regex so i deleted it, but an example of pdf I'm extracting would be this https://bmcimmunol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12865-020-00390-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the abstract is entailed by the strings "Abstract" and "*Correspondence". I'm using str.split() to create a list which contains the text before and after "Abstract". I split the second element of the list creating a list which contains the text before "*Correspondence" and the text after "*Correspondence". The first element of the second list is the abstract. I append everything but the abstract to another variable. Since the abstract is contained on the first page this is only applied to the first page. The first page is selected by using enumerate.

```
import pdfplumber as pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open("s12865-020-00390-9.pdf") as pdf:
    text_without_abstract = ''
    abstract = ''
    for index, pdf_page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        if index == 0:
            single_page_text = pdf_page.extract_text()
            split_at_abstract = single_page_text.split("Abstract")
            text_without_abstract += split_at_abstract[0]
            split_at_asterisk_correspondence = split_at_abstract[1].split("*Correspondence")
            abstract = split_at_asterisk_correspondence[0]
            text_without_abstract += split_at_asterisk_correspondence[1]
        else:
            text_without_abstract += pdf_page.extract_text()
```

Caution: This approach is very dependent on the string content of the document. It will not work if the string "Abstract" occurs inside the abstract or the first string after the abstract is not "*Correspondence".

str.split() : https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: thank you for the help and I just wanted to ask would there be a way to add an if statement to this as in some pdfs the subheading Background appear first.

Comment: Your welcome! Can you link an example for a pdf where the subheading background appears first? I can then adjust the code.

Comment: There is this one where introduction straight after abstract section https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12929-020-00689-0      
  Here is a different one ; https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12929-020-00693-4